# Could someone kindly translate this for me

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ecclesiastical-latin

If it is too long could only this be translated?:

(nisi ei sit super conferendis eisdem in Curia Romana vacantibus specialis et expressa ab ipso Pontifice auctoritas attributa)

__

«Licet ecclesiarum, personatuum, dignitatum aliorumque beneficiorum ecclesiasticorum plenaria dispositio ad Romanum noscatur Pontificem pertinere ita, quod non solum ipsa quum vacant, potest de iure conferre, verum etiam ius in ipsis tribuere vacaturis: collationem tamen ecclesiarum, personatuum, dignitatem et beneficiorum apud sedem apostolicam vacantium specialius ceteris antiqua consuetudo Romanis Pontificibus reservavit.
Nos itaque, laudabilem reputantes huiusmodi consuetudinem, et eam auctoritate apostolica approbantes, ac nihilominus volentes ipsam inviolabiliter observari, eadem auctoritate statuimus, ut ecclesias, personatus, dignitates et beneficia, quae apud Seden ipsam deinceps vacare contingerit, aliquis praeter Romanum Pontificem, quacunque super hoc sit auctoritate munitus, sive iure ordinariae potestatis ipsorum electio, provisio seu collatio ed eum pertineat, sive litteras super aliquorum provisione generales vel etiam speciales sub quacumque forma receperit, (nisi ei sit super conferendis eisdem in Curia Romana vacantibus specialis et expressa ab ipso Pontifice auctoritas attributa), conferre alicui seu aliquibus non praesumat. Nos enim si secus actum seu attentatum fuerit, decernimus irritum et inane»

Comment: Welcome yo te site! We usually don't do such long translations in a single question, though in this case it seems like a standard Holy See legislative text about vacant sees and the appointing of bishops, that maybe has an official translation. Are you able to provide a source? Do you have a specific question about the issue that may help narrow the question down? I'm certain some of us here are willing to help

Comment: Update: the source is the bull Licet ecclesiarum, from XIII century Pope [Clement IV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Clement_IV)

Comment: Hi Rafael, no, I can't find any translation.
If you would be so kind I would like to know this part.
For I have the doubt if Clement IV says that in vacant sees yes or no bishops can be appointed.

If you want you can answer me in Sapnish

Could you translate this part 
 (nisi ei sit super conferendis eisdem in Curia Romana vacantibus specialis et expressa ab ipso Pontifice auctoritas attributa)

Comment: If that one phrase is all you need, edit the question to reflect that. People would be much more willing to translate a single sentence or two for free than a whole wall of text.

Comment: Thanks cmw, I would need everything to be able to refute a Christian sect that wants to look for a loophole in some consecrations during the vacancy of the Papacy for their own illicitities.
But I would settle for that part.
Sorry for the inconvenience.